# Does it make sense to return fundamental types by const value?

Tags: c++, constants, return-value

Which is better:

```cpp
bool MyClass::someQuery() const;

const bool MyClass::someQuery() const;
```

I've been using `const bool` since I'm sure I remember hearing it's "what the `int`s do" (for e.g. comparison operators) but I can't find evidence of that anywhere, mostly due to it being difficult to Google and IntelliSense not helping out any ;) Can anyone confirm that?

To me returning `const` values (this isn't just about `bool`) makes more sense; it'll prevent temporaries being modified, which is almost always going to be a programmer mistake. I just want something to back that up so I can extol returning `const` values to my colleagues :)

Comment: What is the problem with allowing temporaries to be modified? It can be an important optimization (the compiler can reuse your temporary instead of copying into a new non-const one). It is *not* "almost always a programmer mistake"

Comment: I think the example in Effective C++ is good; "if((a*b) = c)" is most likely a mistake and will be caught by making operator* return a const value. Something like "normalise(crossProduct(a,b))" is another one, if normalise modifies its input rather than returning a modified copy - making crossProduct return a const value would catch this.

Comment: @Ben: If normalise() modifies it's input then it's either a (T x) and by that a local variable. In that case it is free to modify it but it will never be "returned" (because it's local to normalise). If it is a (T &x) then you cannot call it that way because you cannot pass rvalues as non-const references! So you must declare normalise as T normalise(T x) or T normalise(const T &x) to call it in the way you did. Otherwise the compiler would complain.

Comment: @Ben i order that into the corner "prefer 0 == v instead of v == 0, it will catch 0 = v". It's not really adding anything substantially and it possibly looks weird visually (though this is surely subjective). Const return values are weird IMHO and prevent move construction in c++0x.

Comment: @litb That's the first solid reason given for not using them (all the other reasons amount to "it's pointless"), which is annoying since it now means I have something to weigh up ;)

Comment: @jalf: The compiler can and will elide the copy-constructor if you assign to an lvalue. So returning const doesn't prevent any optimization.

Comment: @Dan how does that contradict anything I said? I never said const would prevent optimizations, just that there's no harm in letting the returned rvalue be non-const.

Comment: FWIW, my current environment has changed since I originally asked the question - I'm working with a compiler that supports rvalue references and move semantics - so now I'm returning by value rather than const value, to allow more optimisations.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So you know it's right, you're just after the Voice of Authority?
Preventing accidental modification of temporaries is very valuable. In general, you should declare as many things as you possibly can `const`, it protects you from a variety of accidents and gives the optimiser useful hints.

D'you have a copy of Scott Meyers' "Effective C++" around? Point them at Item 3 (page 18 in the third edition) ;)

It gives the example of

```
class Rational {...};
const Rational operator* (const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs );

if( (a * b) = c ) // declaring operator *'s return value const causes error to be caught by compiler
```

Comment: No idea why this was getting voted down, it's exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks :)

Not that I'm putting down any other answers of course; I did also ask "which is better" so opinions on added complexity and so on are also welcome.

Comment: This has nothing to do with his question. He hasked about whether it made sense to make a *bool* return value const. And you answer with a complex non-POD type. -1

Comment: @Ben: It was voted down because it has nothing to do with your question. For a bool, or other built-in types, returning const makes zero difference, and this example wouldn't have compiled anyway.

Comment: Actually I did say "this isn't just about bools", and it's only his example that mentions non-bools anyway. Perhaps I should change the title to "Should I return a value or const value?" - is it ok to change titles of questions here or would that just annoy everyone?

Comment: @Ben: Your "(this isn't just about bools)" has probably escaped many readers while the caption "bool or const bool?" caught everybody's eyes. FWIW, I have tried to answer your question taking your small comment into account.

Comment: And "values" could be considered as referring to bools, floats, doubles - i.e. instances of types that are "less OO".

Comment: In response to the other points about "it doesn't matter for bool".  It is beginning to be popular to refer to fundamental types via typedefs.  The logic being that it's easier to port code that refers to "int32_t" than code referring to "int".  There's no reason that for some of those types they'll be implemented as UDTs anyway!  Adding 'const' ensures consistent behaviour.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if an `int32_t` wasn't a POD. That would, for example, prevent it from being used in a `union`. That's not something one would expect.

Comment: @sbi: The union example is a red herring, if you're using unions then you're already at such a low level in the code that abstractions are no longer an option.  On a 64 bit architecture there may not actually be a 32 bit fundamental type, and so 'int32_t' could be a UDT.  The bigger picture is that you might have "Width", "Height" etc which may or may not be UDTs.

Answer (score 38):

This is the case when `const` adds no value but inflates the code and makes the reader think more. What's the point of this `const`? The caller can copy the value into some non-const variable and do whatever he wants with it anyway.

Comment: In my case, I always think less when I think const.

Answer (score 21):

Note that [`if((a*b) = c)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443659/1443688#1443688) won't compile for built-in types anyway, so it is very relevant here whether we're talking built-in types (your question asks for `bool`) or user-defined types.

For built-in types it makes no sense at all, so it shouldn't be used. And for user-defined types, I'm in jalf's camp: What if the caller *wants* to modify the returned object?

I'm not convinced that `if((a*b) = c)` is such a good argument for returning const user-defined types, since I can't remember the last time I've seen a compiler *not* warn about this.

Comment: Ok, but it fails for other reasons. The normalise(crossProduct(a,b)) example is probably better there, though the example I whipped up on codepad fails because I'm guessing it's based on gcc, which disallows binding of temporaries to non-const references... in MSVC it should succeed, against the programmer's intention.

Comment: @Ben: MS calls the ability of their compiler to bind temporaries to non-const references a "feature", bit it is, in fact, a bug.

Comment: See my comment on the question about the normalise(...) "example".
I even didn't mention the MS "it's not a bug, it's a feature" thingy about binding rvalues to non-const references!

Comment: PODs include simple structs like `struct A { int a, b; };`, which will work fine with `(a*b) = c`. But i've heard for C++0x they talk about making the `operator=` only work for lvalues, making this code snippet invalid. I wish that they would do that, but probably they would break too much code :(

Comment: @litb: Dammit, I thought I was on the safe side with PODs! I'll replace them with "built-in types".

Answer (score 21):

To be a little more specific, only "objects" can be const. The C++ standard's definition of "object" includes everything an lvalue refers to ("has a name") and class-type temporaries. A boolean return value is an rvalue of a non-class type which is why a standards-compliant compiler will just ignore "const" in this case. As others said already, it's useless in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail! Does this mean though that it *would* be useful for class types?

Comment: Yes. Some people prefer to return const objects to prevent assignments. This is usually motivated by a possible typo

    if (get_object() = blah) ...

which won't compile if the function get_object() returns a const object (of some class-type). But I never considered this to be a big problem. In the light of C++0x, rvalue references and move semantics returning const objects can be counterproductive and decrease performance. C++0x offers a better solution for preventing assignments on rvalue objects: ref qualifiers.

Answer (score 15):

When you returning a refernce to a member variable it makes sense to make it const. Here you are returning a copy, hence there is no need of const.

Answer (score 9):

The `const` modifier is only used for return types that are returned *by reference* (either as reference `const SomeObject&` or via a pointer `const SomeObject*`), so the caller won't be able to modify the object via the reference/pointer.  Primitive types are returned *by value*, which means that the caller receives a *copy* of the the object, not the object itself.

Therefore, `const` is not really appropriate for returned value types.  Since the copy is outside of the control of the called function, the called function should not dictate to the caller that it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ancient post, but I think it's worth mentioning there is a potential corner case here since C++11. While, as stated by others, it will make no difference whether you use `const bool` or `bool` as return type in most cases, if you are using C++11 `decltype` and associates, e.g. [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), you could declare a variable with the same type as the returning value of some function, and so the `const` would actually have an effect in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It completely doesn't matter. Therefore, the consensus is to return just `bool`.

The reason that it doesn't matter is that you can't call non-const member functions anyway; `bool` is not a class or struct.

Answer (score 2):

As bool is going to be copied, it's the same, to put const or not. Plus you'll may have some compil problems.

Answer (score 1):

[const return type](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppConstReturnType.htm)

> SUMMARY:
>
> The value of a return type that is
>   declared const cannot be changed. This
>   is especially usefull when giving a
>   reference to a class’s internals, but
>   can also prevent rarer errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
const bool func();
bool f = func();
```

0 errors, 0 warnings. What have you accomplished other than unnecessary code inflation?

Comment: That's ok though; the copy is explicit, and any modifications are going to be explicit. It doesn't achieve anything in that circumstance; it's more to prevent accidental modification of temporaries, where modification will be lost at the end of the statement.