# Is the order of method return types and modifiers in C++ important?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have come across a situation that conflicts with my current understanding of methods in C++.

I am working through Ivor Horton's "Beginning Visual C++ 2010" (Wrox Press).  On page 449, Example 8_03, a method is defined as:

```
double Volume() const {
    return m_Length * m_Width * m_Height;
}
```

I had rearranged the modifiers as:

```
double **const** Volume() {
    return m_Length * m_Width * m_Height;
}
```

From my C# and Java background, I had expected the position of const to be irrelevant, but on compilation I received the error:

```
error C2662: 'CBox::Volume' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 
             'const CBox' to 'CBox &'
```

The error disappears when I return the order to the way Ivor has it.

Does the order in fact make a difference and this not some exotic bug ?  If order does matter, how does one remember the correct positions ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `const` is placed after the name of a member method, that is stating that the `this` pointer is what is constant.  That is to say, the original declaration states that the method `CBox::Volume()` does not change  the `CBox` object on which it is called.

The most likely source of error is that the `CBox::Volume()` function is being called on a `const CBox`, or inside another `const` method of that `CBox`.

Comment: Ah, yes!  This was it exactly - the compiler was upset regarding this and const.  So the fact that the const is appended to the end of the method is just a standard rule...const at end means this is const ?  I guess the loosey-goosey world of Java/C# is too forgiving :)

Comment: @Scott: Java isn't too forgiving, but it doesn't have type qualifiers. When using `const` it matters which part of a complex type it is that you're modifying `int const *` isn't the same as `int * const`, because the const-ness applies to different things. Similarly the position of the `const` in a member function declaration is meaningful. And note, "member function" - if you keep calling them methods, you'll keep unconsciously thinking of C++ as Java in a different hat, and it isn't :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a `const` after the member function name means the function itself is `const`--basically, it means you cannot modify the object within the member function.  The const before the member function means the return type is `const`.  (Though it can get complicated for return types, and I don't want to get into that here :) )

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** To be more concise.

`const` in those two contexts is very different.

```
double Volume() const {
    return m_Length * m_Width * m_Height;
}
```

This is called when the instantiation of the object is `const` and returns a `double`. If you were to try and call that method with a non-const instance, it will not compile.

```
 const myClass obj;
 double d = obj.volume();
 myClass obj2;
 double d = obj2.volume(); // This Fails to compile
```

On the other hand ...

```
double const Volume() {
    return m_Length * m_Width * m_Height;
}
```

is called when the object isn't a `const` or if the previous definition doesn't exist.

```
myClass obj;
const double d = obj.volume();
const myClass obj2;
const double d = obj2.volume();
```

(I should mention as I was reminded below, returning a const built-in type such as `double` it doesn't really mean anything.)

When you have both of these declared the appropriate one will be called depending if the instance is const or not.

```
myClass obj;
const double d = obj.volume(); // This calls `const double volume()`
const myClass obj2;
double d = obj2.volume(); // This calls 'double volume() const`
```

Comment: Your last snippet is perhaps a bit misleading. The return value can be stored in a non-const `double` and subsequently changed. [Returning a built-in type as `const` has no effect.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443659/should-i-return-bool-or-const-bool)

Comment: Yeah ... you know, I thought about that after the fact. With the built in type it's not so cut and dry. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: This gives a somewhat false impression that `obj` has to be const to call the first, and that the result has to be assigned to a const double in the second case. http://ideone.com/6hBWH (The second case should actually be rather pointless - G++ even warns that top level const qualifier is ignored on return type.)

Comment: I should have been far more concise, that should be better.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` after the method name tells the compiler that the method will not modify any data members (`mutable` members are an exception).

The `const` before the method name applies to the return value.  This tells the compiler that the method returns constant data.  The `const` for the return type is primarily used with references and pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the order is important.

In C++ the position of the const keyword will have an impact on what item is "const".  The same goes for the scope the const keyword is used in.