# Functions returning a const value

Tags: c++, return, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should useless type qualifiers on return types be used, for clarity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579435/should-useless-type-qualifiers-on-return-types-be-used-for-clarity)

I am confused as to returning by value and returning a const value. For instance in any function once the function is done, all locals go out of scope. So if I am returning a value from a function it has to be a pass by copy, unless its a return by reference. So when this happens the function returns a copy which can be modified later on. So even if a local variable was declared const I can read it in another variable and modify the latter with ease.

```
const int DoubleValue(int nX)
{
    int nValue = nX * 2;
    return nValue; // A copy of nValue will be returned here
} // n
```

I am confused as to figuring out what does `const` mean here. Is `nValue` const in the function body? If I do an assign as to, as in `z = DoubleValue(x);`, I can obviously modify `z`.

Under what circumstance is the constness enforced? Is the object `DoubleValue(x)` a const object? What does it represent?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443659/should-i-return-bool-or-const-bool for a discussion of when this makes a difference.

Comment: It makes no difference with `const int`; it matters if you return a `const char *` or something like that.  The `const` then says that the calling code may not modify the value (string) pointed at.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is totally correct; `const char *` is equivalent to `char const *` rather than `char * const` :-)

Comment: A similar (but less concrete) question here: [Should useless type qualifiers on return types be used, for clarity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579435/should-useless-type-qualifiers-on-return-types-be-used-for-clarity)

Answer (score 8):

There is a corner case where you returning a const value will make a difference. If I remember correctly from one of Scott Meyers' books, if you overload an operator (say +) and you return a value that is not `const` you could do something like:

```
A + B = C;
```

Which is not something you want to allow. The following code compiles (but if you replace `A` by `const A` in the operator it won't):

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int i): i_(i) {}
    A operator +(A& rhs) { return A(i_ + rhs.i_); }

private:
    int i_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a(1);
    A b(2);
    A c(3);

    a + b = c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no issue allowing `A + B = C`, since it's not something you want to *write* anyway.

Comment: @YvesgereY which is exactly why you should disallow it.

Comment: "A + B = C" is certainly something I'd allow, depending on what it means :) Expression Templates do things like this with generative power a lot

Comment: @sehe would you mind giving an example for the curious?